# Get the number of seconds from a duration

Tags: time, libreoffice, duration, calc

I'm looking for some help about getting a number of seconds from a text.

This is what i have in libreoffice calc column A :

- A1 : 35 days 21 hours 56 minutes
- A2 : 3 days 0 hours 54 minutes
- A3 : 1 days 3 hours 0 minutes
- A4 : 5 hours 26 minutes
- A5 : 32 minutes
- A6 : 0 second

And I'm looking for a solution (I'm bad with Libreoffice Basic) to get seconds from this durations in column B. Problem is from parsing the column (this is count as text, and formatting this in data still don't work). I don't know how to split the cell to get for example : `35*86400+21*3600+56*60` for cell `A1`.

I tried to split with the libreoffice tool, but if i don't have days in column A, it makes for example : `5(hours)*86400`, etc.. for cell `A4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starbasic with libreoffice API:

```
function GETSECONDS(s1 as string) as long
 oFuncAccess = createUnoService( "com.sun.star.sheet.FunctionAccess" )
 s1 = oFuncAccess.callFunction("SUBSTITUTE", array(s1, "days", "*24*60*60+"))
 s1 = oFuncAccess.callFunction("SUBSTITUTE", array(s1, "hours", "*60*60+"))
 s1 = oFuncAccess.callFunction("SUBSTITUTE", array(s1, "minutes", "*60+"))
 s1 = oFuncAccess.callFunction("SUBSTITUTE", array(s1, "seconds", "*1+"))
 s1 = left(s1, len(s1)-1)
 lRes = 0
 sAdd = split(s1, "+")
 for i = lbound(sAdd) to ubound(sAdd)
  sMult = split(sAdd(i),"*")
  lResMult = 1
  for j = lbound(sMult) to ubound(sMult)
   lResMult = lResMult * val(sMult(j))
  next
  lRes = lRes + lResMult
 next 
 getSeconds = lRes
end function
```

To use as UDF like: `=GETSECONDS(A1)`

The time measurement units have to be in plural form.

Greetings

Axel

Comment: TY it works very well ! I didn't thought about substitue my text in multiplication. Ty very much

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say about your preferred language, I can show you an example in PHP. The goal is to leave only numbers in string and affter it calculate the sum. I don't know all possible variants of strings, but this code works for your input.

```
$durations = array(
    '35 days 21 hours 56 minutes',
    '3 days 0 hours 54 minutes',
    '1 days 3 hours 0 minutes',
    '5 hours 26 minutes',
    '32 minutes',
    '0 second'
);
$constants = array(60, 3600, 86400);
$durationsTime = array();
foreach ($durations as $duration) {
    $numbers = preg_replace('/[^0-9\s]/i', '', $duration);
    $values  = explode('  ', $numbers);
    $time    = 0;
    if (count($values) > 1) {
        foreach ($values as $key => $value) {
            $time += $value * $constants[count($values) - $key - 1];
        }
    } else {
        $time = strpos($duration, 'second') !== false ? intval($values[0]) : $values[0] * $constants[0];
    }

    $durationsTime[] = $time;
}
var_dump($durationsTime);die();
```

Comment: Actually i would like to know if there is a way to do it with libreoffice. But i keep this if i have to build it in Basic. Thank you for your help